# I don't have anything in my database?

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')" or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

I wrote this code... I don't have anything in my base after inputing

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Many thing coul be at fault,do you get any errors?It might be as simple as needing to refresh your client data.Assuming id is a primary key you should use DEFAULT instead of NULL

Comment: Any errors? What is `$con`? There's information we are missing.

Comment: There is no error I just after typing uname, lname and all other and pressing submit  didn't have anything in databse

Comment: is your ID field set in your database as AUTO_INCREMENT? if so the NULL in the values section could be causing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')" or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Replace with:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (name, lname, uname, email, pass) VALUES ('$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')" or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

No need to put your column names in quotes.

Also, if your ID is auto_increment, you don't need to add it in your insert query.

Comment: You removed the backticks around the fields but not the table name?

Comment: No need to remove it around the table name. That is generally accepted by sql :)

Comment: Thanks that was the problem :)

Comment: @AmarMuratović: Be sure to mark this answer as the answer you needed. That way people know that you have the answer you need :)

Comment: @ChrisG *Backticks are only needed when your table name or column name is a MySQL reserved word*.

Comment: @Script47: Oh, didn't know that. Thanks for that! :)

Comment: @ChrisG glad I could help.

Comment: Why have you removed the backticks they are quite legal as they were

Comment: Also the INSERT query line must generate a syntax error somewhere as the brackets dont match and an `or die()` there makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

An `or die(mysqli_error($con));` makes no sense as part of setting a string literal. So try recoding like this so that you are looking for errors from the right place.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` 
                 (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) 
          VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    exit;
}
```